# .Net timers work threads

Tags: .net, multithreading, timer, c++-cli

I'm currently trying to understand how do timers in .net work in regard to multithread application. Using Visual Studio 2010, .NET/C++/CLI.
The task is to have a timer that will read some data on background, so that I can show that data via another timer. Quite simple, though...

I made a simple programm to watch how different timers work:
1. **System::Windows::Forms::Timer**;
2. **System::Timers::Timer**;
3. **System::Threading::Timer**;
4. and another **System::Timers::Timer** that I run not from main thread, but **using System::Threading::Thread**.
All of them are made manually in code, and there is another one timer made in Designer that is of type System::Windows::Forms::Timer
Each timer write a string to it's own container of type *ConcurrentQueue* every tick and increments its counter, that is global variable of type int. Main thread timer gets those strings to the interface list Control.

[**programm snapshot**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AuDOd.png)

All four timers initialized to tick every 500ms.
 
First **number** in list is a tick counter. 
**Text** in **<>** is thread name. 
**Id:** is an id of the thread. 
**T:** is the real time that has passed between ticks - calculated using *QueryPerformanceCounter()* function in every event.

Now we see that timers started simultaneously work for first 5 ticks. Also we see that only first timer uses same thread every tick.
Then I press the Sleep button that implements **Sleep(5000)** function on the main thread imitating it is really busy.
As expected, the first one just stops and continues after sleep.
But others work strange to me. I expect them to run on background. But what I see is that counters are not incremented properly and time for a tick is not correct also.

*What I would like to know is are those timers (Timers::Timer and Threading::Timer) really somehow blocked by main thread sleeping function, or it is just a* **UI bug/code mistakes** *or they* **work fine** *actually?*

*Here what happens on timer tick. Similar to every timer:*

```
System::Void Form1::SysThrd_Tick(System::Object^  sender)
{
    static LARGE_INTEGER ticks_old, ticks_new;  //for precise counter
    double real_time=0;

    if (Thread::CurrentThread->Name == nullptr) Thread::CurrentThread->Name = "ThTm";
    Thread_Timer_Id = GetThreadId(GetCurrentThread());

    QueryPerformanceCounter(&ticks_new);  //getting precise ticks

    real_time = safe_cast<double>(ticks_new.QuadPart - ticks_old.QuadPart);
    real_time = real_time/freq.QuadPart;  //counting real time passed for tick

    ThTm_queue->Enqueue(SysThrd_tick.ToString()+" <"+Thread::CurrentThread->Name+"> Id: "+Thread_Timer_Id+"; T: "+real_time.ToString("0.000"));  //adding item to container

    SysThrd_tick++;
    ticks_old = ticks_new;
}
```

Showing data from containers is via designer timer:

```
System::Void Form1::InnerTimer_Tick(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e)
{
    String ^str;
    static int Inner_tick=0;

    InnerTimer_tB->Text = Thread::CurrentThread->Name+"::"+Inner_tick.ToString();  //text to Form1 TextBox control
    Inner_tick++;

    while (!ThTm_queue->IsEmpty) 
    {
        ThTm_queue->TryDequeue(str);  //getting item from container
        Threading_Timer_lB->Items->Add(str); //adding item to Form1 ListBox control
    }
//<similar code for other containers>
}
```

All containers defined in Form1.h and initialized in main.cpp like this:

```
void Form1::init_queues()
{
    ThTm_queue = gcnew ConcurrentQueue<String^>;
    //same code for other containers
}
```

Tick counters are global integers and defined in resource.h

Timers are defined in Form1.h and initialized in main.cpp, for example Threading::Timer:

```
System::Void Form1::Init_Timers()
{
    //other timers initialization
    Form1::SysThrd_Timer = gcnew System::Threading::Timer((gcnew TimerCallback(this, &Form1::SysThrd_Tick)), nullptr, Threading::Timeout::Infinite, Threading::Timeout::Infinite);
}
```

Comment: We cannot help you without a [mcve]. We need to see what your code does.

Comment: Agree. At least some additional code is needed even to reproduce the issue locally. Otherwise it's hard to determine if there is any code-specific behavior.

Comment: are those two fragments not enough?

Comment: At least initialization of timers/queues and other form fields is needed. Along with their types. For example it's hard to tell without additinal investigation what types `FmTm_queue` and `Forms_Timer_lB` have.
It'll also be nice to narrow down the example to two timers one of which behaves as expected, while other doesn't. Or even to single timer.